# Python Google People API - what is the python format to update a contact?

Tags: python

What is the python code that allows me to update a contact. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I gain access to the service via:

```
service = discovery.build('people', 'v1', http=http,
                          discoveryServiceUrl='https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest')
```

I create the contact to update via:

```
contactToUpdate = service.people().get(resourceName = resourceName, personFields = "nicknames").execute()
```

where the resourceName  is a people/xxxxxxx.

I don't know how to create the actual update.
What is the format and what are the expected argument?

I have tried:

```
updatedContact = service.people().updateContact(resourceName = resourceName).updatePersonFields(resourceName = resourceName, body = {
    "etag": etag,
    "nicknames": [
        {
            "metadata": {
                "primary": True,
                "source": {
                    "type": "CONTACT"
                }
            },
            "value": "xxxx"
        }
    ]

})
```

and get an error message saying:

```
  File "/home/marc/Pycharm2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 737, in method
    raise TypeError('Missing required parameter "%s"' % name)
TypeError: Missing required parameter "body"
```

Comment: Can you format your code so that it’s easier to read?

Comment: apologies.  My viewed format looked better than the one that is posted above.